# View model not being recognized within Maui Content Page View

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am trying to understand services in terms of Maui but the injection is not reconizing it in the view.

```
namespace FoodOrder.ViewModels
{
public class MenusViewModel
{
    IMenuServiceInterface _menuServiceInterface;
    IFoodOrderHttpClientInterface _foodOrderHttpClientInterface;
    public MenusViewModel(IMenuServiceInterface 
       menuServiceInterface, IFoodOrderHttpClientInterface 
       foodOrderHttpClientInterface)
    {
        _foodOrderHttpClientInterface = foodOrderHttpClientInterface;
    }   
}
}
```

View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="FoodOrder.Pages.MenuPage"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FoodOrder.ViewModels"
        Title="MenuPage">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
<vm:MenusViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
<Label Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
public MenuPage(MenusViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = viewModel;
}
}
```

MauiProgram.cs

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IFoodOrderHttpClientInterface, 
     FoodOrderHttpClientServices>();

    return builder.Build();
}
}
```

Comment: *"the injection is not reconizing it in the view"* Please be precise when describing a symptom. Are you getting some error, or does a breakpoint on or after line `_foodOrderHttpClientInterface = foodOrderHttpClientInterface;` show that the parameter `foodOrderHttpClientInterface` is null? And sorry to ask an obvious question, but I don't see declaration of the class, is it `class FoodOrderHttpClientServices : IFoodOrderHttpClientInterface`?

Comment: Its more to do with the front end xaml in old days we would need to add the view model there as well are u saying in maui land we dont need to do it both places yes FoodOrderHttpClientServices  is a class with an interface of IFoodOrderHttpClientInterface  it just to much code to put here @ToolmakerSteve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have Maui apply Dependency Injection, you **also** need to declare the viewmodel in which injection should occur.

Add this line to builder:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<MenusViewModel>();
```

---

BTW, if there are many views and viewmodels to add to Services for DI, can make a bit more concise like this:

```cs
var diTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(MainPage), typeof(Page2), typeof(Page3), typeof(Page4) };
diTypes.ForEach(ty => builder.Services.AddTransient(ty));
```

Comment: So that and my service got u makes since

Comment: Yeah, it becomes a lot of lines to add to builder. I hope eventually an attribute on each class to inject will be an alternative. Or a way to have all subclasses of a given class be recognized for injection.

Comment: or just extract into a serviceCollection, then use that 1 liner in the builder