# Dependency injection with JobService subclass in MAUI application

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, maui

[for Android platform]

Is there any way to inject dependencies into `JobService` subclass?
In order to compile `JobService` subclass must not contain constructor with parameters and from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-job-scheduler#creating-a-jobinfo-to-schedule-a-job) you can only use `SetExtras` to send some simple data to it.

So what should I do in order to use a service that is in a DI container, resolve it using IServiceProvider or something else?

Comment: *"In order to compile JobService subclass must not contain constructor with parameters"* - not necessarily. In App.xaml.cs where there is App builder code, you can add additional Services. Add one for `JobParameters` and one for `YourJobServiceSubclass`. Then DI can resolve a `JobParameters` parameter in the constructor of `YourJobServiceSubclass`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72503206/199364 - I show a fairly concise way to add a bunch of types as Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion I found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnetMAUI/comments/vfiz45/access_di_objects_in_androids_mainactivity_class/) it constructor injection is a common issue with Android activities/services etc. but there seems to be a workaround by using dependency resolver the way James Montemagno describes it [here](https://youtu.be/xx1mve2AQr4?t=570).